# After upgrade PHP to 7.4 to 8.1 version the sites are not up

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, drupal

We have one application that is hosted in AWS Ec2 instance and the operating system is centos 7.

The application is based on drupal framework. previously our server has PHP 7.4 installed. Last week we upgrade PHP version to 7.4 to 8.1.13.

We follow the below mention steps to upgrade the php.

```
sudo yum-config-manager --disable 'remi-php*'
sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php81
sudo yum -y install php php-{cli,fpm,mysqlnd,zip,devel,gd,mbstring,curl,xml,pear,bcmath,json,opcache,redis,memcache}
```

After that from server when we run php -v command we see the updated version 8.1.13 but from browser it show

```
handle($request);$response->send();$Kernel->terminate($request,$response);
```

My observation :

During the upgrade I find below warning massages.

> PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'opcache' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache (/usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: bcmath: Unable to initialize module
> Module compiled with module API=20190902
> PHP    compiled with module API=20200930

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'dom' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/dom (/usr/lib64/php/modules/dom: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so: undefined symbol: zend_wrong_parameters_none_exception)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: gd: Unable to initialize module
> Module compiled with module API=20190902
> PHP    compiled with module API=20200930

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'json' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/json (/usr/lib64/php/modules/json: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so: undefined symbol: _call_user_function_ex)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mbstring: Unable to initialize module
> Module compiled with module API=20190902
> PHP    compiled with module API=20200930

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysqlnd: Unable to initialize module
> Module compiled with module API=20190902
> PHP    compiled with module API=20200930
> These options need to match

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so: undefined symbol: zend_wrong_parameters_count_exception)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: posix: Unable to initialize module
> Module compiled with module API=20190902
> PHP    compiled with module API=20200930

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'simplexml' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/simplexml (/usr/lib64/php/modules/simplexml: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/simplexml.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/simplexml.so: undefined symbol: zend_parse_parameters_throw)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sodium' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/sodium (/usr/lib64/php/modules/sodium: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/sodium.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/sodium.so: undefined symbol: zend_parse_parameters_throw)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite3 (/usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite3.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite3.so: undefined symbol: zend_parse_parameters_throw)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sysvmsg: Unable to initialize module

Module compiled with module API=20190902

> PHP    compiled with module API=20200930
> These options need to match
> in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sysvsem: Unable to initialize module
> Module compiled with module API=20190902
> PHP    compiled with module API=20200930
> These options need to match
> in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sysvshm: Unable to initialize module
> Module compiled with module API=20190902
> PHP    compiled with module API=20200930
> These options need to match
> in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: xml: Unable to initialize module
> Module compiled with module API=20190902
> PHP    compiled with module API=20200930
> These options need to match

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/xsl (/usr/lib64/php/modules/xsl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/xsl.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/xsl.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_class_entry)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xmlreader' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlreader (/usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlreader: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlreader.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlreader.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_class_entry)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so: undefined symbol: _call_user_function_ex), /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'igbinary.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/igbinary.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/igbinary.so: undefined symbol: _call_user_function_ex), /usr/lib64/php/modules/igbinary.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/igbinary.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcache.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcache.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcache.so: undefined symbol: _call_user_function_ex), /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcache.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcache.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so: undefined symbol: igbinary_serialize), /usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

> PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Installer/Role.php on line 250

> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "honorsbaseinstall" in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Installer/Role.php on line 173

> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "installable" in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Installer/Role.php on line 139

> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "phpfile" in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Installer/Role.php on line 204

> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "config_vars" in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Installer/Role.php on line 46

> PHP Warning:  foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

---

and when I check /usr/lib64/php/modules path I find these PHP modules.

```
bcmath.so    curl.so      ftp.so      igbinary.so  mysqli.so     pdo.so         redis.so      sodium.so   sysvshm.so    xmlwriter.so
bz2.so       dom.so       gd.so       mbstring.so  mysqlnd.so    pdo_sqlite.so  shmop.so      sqlite3.so  tokenizer.so  xsl.so
calendar.so  exif.so      gettext.so  memcache.so  opcache.so    phar.so        simplexml.so  sysvmsg.so  xmlreader.so  zip.so
ctype.so     fileinfo.so  iconv.so    msgpack.so   pdo_mysql.so  posix.so       sockets.so    sysvsem.so  xml.so
```

Please help me to solve the issue why from browser I see this error

```
handle($request);$response->send();$Kernel->terminate($request,$response);
```

Comment: Warnings during an update to a major version are expected. Check using "php -m" to ensure all extensions load fine.  Have you restart the web server ?

Comment: Hi Remi Collect I restart the httpd service and also I check php -m command all extensions are successfully loaded